# What would be a reason to use ADDS instruction instead of the ADD instruction in ARM assembly?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

My course notes always use ADDS and SUBS in their ARM code snippets, instead of the ADD and SUB as I would expect. Here's one such snippet for example:

```
__asm void my_capitalize(char *str)
{
cap_loop
  LDRB r1, [r0]   // Load byte into r1 from memory pointed to by r0 (str pointer)
  CMP r1, #'a'-1  // compare it with the character before 'a'
  BLS cap_skip    // If byte is lower or same, then skip this byte
  CMP r1, #'z'    // Compare it with the 'z' character
  BHI cap_skip    // If it is higher, then skip this byte
  SUBS r1,#32     // Else subtract out difference to capitalize it
  STRB r1, [r0]   // Store the capitalized byte back in memory

cap_skip
  ADDS r0, r0, #1 // Increment str pointer
  CMP r1, #0      // Was the byte 0?
  BNE cap_loop    // If not, repeat the loop
  BX lr           // Else return from subroutine
}
```

This simple code for example converts all lowercase English in a string to uppercase. What I do not understand in this code is why they are not using ADD and SUB commands instead of ADDS and SUBS currently being used. The ADDS and SUBS command, afaik, update the APSR flags NZCV, for later use. However, as you can see in the above snippet, the updated values are not being utilized. Is there any other utility of this command then?

Comment: I think you'd have to ask whoever wrote the code. Perhaps that person or persons use a coding style where the default is to always update the status flags.

Comment: @Michael Sure, I'll attempt to contact the person who wrote this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arithmetic instructions (`ADD`, `SUB`, etc) don't modify the status flag, unlike comparison instructions (`CMP`,`TEQ`) which update the condition flags by default. However, adding the `S` to the arithmetic instructions(`ADDS`, `SUBS`, etc) will update the condition flags according to the result of the operation. That is the only point of using the `S` for the arithmetic instructions, so if the cf are not going to be checked, there is no reason to use `ADDS` instead of `ADD`.

---

There are more codes to append to the instruction ([link](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes)), in order to achieve different purposes, such as `CC` (the conditional flag C=0), hence:

`ADDCC`: do the operation if the carry status bit is set to 0.

`ADDCCS`: do the operation if the carry status bit is set to 0 and afterwards, update the status flags (if C=1, the status flags are not overwritten).

---

From the cycles point of view, there is no difference between updating the conditional flags or not. Considering an [ARMv6-M](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html) as example, `ADDS` and `ADD` will take 1 cycle.

---

Discard the use of `ADD` might look like a lazy choice, since `ADD` is quite useful for some cases. Going further, consider these examples:

```
  SUBS r0, r0, #1
  ADDS r0, r0, #2
  BNE go_wherever
```

and

```
  SUBS r0, r0, #1
  ADD r0, r0, #2
  BNE go_wherever
```

may yield different behaviours.

---

As old_timer has pointed out, the [UAL](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731145130.html) becomes quite relevant on this topic. Talking about the unified language, the preferred syntax is `ADDS`, instead of `ADD` ([link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/BABJIHGJ.html)). So the OP's code is absolutely fine (even recommended) if the purpose is to be assembled for Thumb and/or ARM (using UAL).

Comment: Since you mention ARMv6-M, It may be worth mentioning that in the 16-bit thumb encoding some combinations (such as ADD r5, #5) are not expressable and that in full thumb 2 the instruction may differ in size, e.g. ADD r5, #5 is 32 bit while ADDS r5, #5 is 16 bit.

Answer (score 5):

ADD without the flag update is not available on some cortex-ms.  If you look at the arm documentation for the instruction set (always a good idea when doing assembly language) for general purpose use cases that is not available until a thumb2 extension on armv7-m (cortex-m3, cortex-m4, cortex-m7).  The cortex-m0 and cortex-m0+ and generally wide compatibility code (which would use armv4t or armv6-m) doesn't have an add without flags option.  So perhaps that is why.

The other reason may be to get the 16-bit instruction not the 32, but but that is a slippery slope as it gets even more into assemblers and their syntax (syntax is defined by the assembler, the program that processes assembly language, not the target). For example not syntax unified gas:

```
.thumb
add r1,r2,r3

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   18d1        adds    r1, r2, r3
```

The disassembler knows reality but the assembler doesn't:

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:2: Error: instruction not supported in Thumb16 mode -- `adds r1,r2,r3'
```

but

```
.syntax unified
.thumb
adds r1,r2,r3
add r1,r2,r3


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   18d1        adds    r1, r2, r3
   2:   eb02 0103   add.w   r1, r2, r3
```

So not slippery in this case, but with the unified syntax you start to get into blahw, blah.w, blah, type syntax and have to spin back around to check to see that the instructions you wanted are being generated.  Non-unified has its own games as well, and of course all of this is assembler-specific.

I suspect they were either going with the only choice they had, or were using the smaller and more compatible instruction, especially if this were a class or text, the more compatible the better.